# Is it possible to Inherit from a structure without having another initialized structure in C

Tags: c, oop, pointers, inheritance, structure

I am a new data structures student and trying to get familiar with c structs. I know inheritance from my past python experiences so I wanted to pseudo try it in c. My code goes like this:

```
typedef struct{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    int weight;
    int selling_price;
} Animal;

typedef struct{
    Animal *animal;
    int can_speak;
}super_animal;

int main() {
    Animal monkey;
    strcpy(monkey.name,"Mustafa");
    monkey.age=19;
    monkey.weight=80;

    super_animal human;
    human.animal=&monkey;
    human.can_speak=1;
    printf("%s, can speak bool:%d\n",human.animal->name,human.can_speak);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to cut that middle monkey step from the code.Is it possible to use an unassigned structure pointer like that?

Comment: what's the "middle monkey step"? If you're going to dereference the `animal` pointer, then it needs to point to valid memory or you invoke undefined behavior. You have correctly assigned it to the address of `monkey` here.

Comment: @yano Hmm i understand. But can't i just for example create an char array and store my name in there. Then pass that to human.animal->name without even assigning human.animal to &monkey. The char array also has a valid and accessible memory adress.

Comment: Why don't you make `Animal` a member of super_animal, without pointer?

Comment: @TarekDakhran oh. I thought we had to use a pointer to store a struct in a struct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as `animal` has type `Animal *`, it **must** point to valid memory before it is used. That memory does not have to have a name or be referenced by another pointer with a name. That is, you can remove the separate `monkey` variable by directly allocating memory for the `human`:

```
super_animal human = { .animal = malloc(sizeof *human.animal), .can_speak = 1 };
if (human.animal == NULL)
    HandleError();
strcpy(human.animal->name, "Mustafa");
human.animal->age = 19;
human.animal->weight = 80;
```

If you instead change the type of the `animal` member to `Animal` instead of `Animal *`:

```
typedef struct{
    Animal animal;
    int can_speak;
}super_animal;
```

thus embedding an `Animal` structure directly in the `super_animal` structure, then you do not need to provide separate memory:

```
super_animal human = { .animal.name = "Mustafa", .animal.age = 19, .animal.weight = 80, .can_speak = 1 };
printf("%s, can speak bool:%d\n",human.animal.name,human.can_speak);
```

Note that this changes `.animal.name` to point to a string literal directly instead of making a copy of it. That is not necessary for this example. There are a variety of ways to decide how to handle the name, how to initialize the structure, and so on.

Comment: This answered all my questions thank you very much.